# como descargar un archivo de linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Tengo el archivo `bkup-gcp-htdocs.tar.gz` en el directorio `backups`

```
root@api-vm-vm:~# cd backups
root@api-vm-vm:~/backups# ls
bkup-gcp-htdocs.tar.gz
root@api-vm-vm:~/backups#
```

En el SSH le doy la opcion de `Descargar Archivo` el cual me pide una ruta, le doy `backups/bkup-gcp-htdocs.tar.gz` y me dice que el archivo no existe...

Que ruta le debo dar? o que otro método utilizo para descargarlo?

Comment: diría que `~/backups/...`, ¿no?

Comment: No, tampoco es.

Comment: No entiendo bien. Tienes dos máquinas: en la primera tienes un archivo en la ruta `/root/backups/bkup-gcp-htdocs.tar.gz`, y en la segunda quieres descargar ese archivo a través de ssh?

Comment: Pues si, es una VM en un VPS y el archivo lo voy a descargar a mi maquina con windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Lo cambie de directorio

```
root@api-vm-vm:~# mv backups /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs
root@api-vm-vm:/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs# cd /backups
root@api-vm-vm:/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/backups# ls
bkup-gcp-htdocs.tar.gz
```

Le di la ruta

```
/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/backups/bkup-gcp-htdocs.tar.gz
```

Y así lo dejo descargar, pero no creo que sea la forma, me queda la incógnita